# Sum Column and Show repeated in an Extra Column

Tags: mysql, sum, calculated-columns

I need your help, I am a beginner in MySQL, I want to know the following, I add an image that shows a table, I need to know how to get the sum of the values of column A and show the result duplicate times in the column yellow which is called sum_A.  I would really appreciate your help. :)

[image: table-data]

Comment: Here's a guide how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this. orders is your main table. Quantity is your sum column.

```
drop temporary table temp_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table select ID,Quantity from orders;
set @totalQuantitty=(select sum(Quantity) from temp_table);

select *,@totalQuantitty from temp_table
```

Comment: Thanks @ORCAs This really help to my question, but I did something different but also works I try a SELECT followed by a SET function, but I don't know if it is an efficient way to implement
...
SET Sum_A = ( SELECT IF( SUM(A) FROM ... ) 
...

Comment: If it helped to you to solve your problem you should choose the answer as a solution for making my effort valuable. Otherwise next time nobody will effort to solve your problems.